# mvc call api controller PostAsJsonAsync action Method name Get

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am doing an *Asp .Net MVC 5 APP* and I am calling an API Controller using `PostAsJsonAsync` like this

```
int value=0;
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiUrl + "Method/Action",value);
```

My Api Controller Method look like this...

```
[ActionName("GetByUpload")]
public int ByUpload([FromBody]long id)
{
    return 100;
}
```

If the Method Name starts with `GET` give me an error `405`

Why can´t call a method started with Get?

Any way can call Get..something?

Comment: Decorate it with a `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are intending to post to that action, you need to explicitly assign a `HttpPost` attribute to the action so that the route table knows how to match requests to that action .

```
[HttPost]
[ActionName("GetByUpload")]
public int ByUpload([FromBody]long id)
{
    return 100;
}
```